# Set formula from different worksheet PHPExcel does not take correct values

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to create a drop down in my excel using a separate worksheet.

```
    // Creating original sheet.
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();


    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // Creating auxiliary sheet for drop down data.
    $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet(0);
    $objWorkSheet->setTitle("autofill");
    $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('A1', 2)
                 ->setCellValue('A2', 3);


    $objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2')->getDataValidation();
    $objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
    $objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
    $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
    $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
    $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
    $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
    $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
    $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
    $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
    $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
    // Setting the formula in original sheet.
    $objValidation->setFormula1("='autofill'!$A$1:$A$2");
```

I get a drop down in B2 cell but only with a single value 0( as shown in the image).

[image]

Can somebody please point out the error in the code?

Comment: Don't treat it as a formula; just as a cell reference: `$objValidation->setFormula1('autofill!$A$1:$A$2');` especially as you don't need to quote the worksheet name

Comment: P.S. Version 2.1 of PHPExcel doesn't exist; latest production release is 1.8.1

Comment: @MarkBaker This made it work.

Comment: @MarkBaker Drop down breaks and shows only a zero when there are too many entries in the list(say, 20000).Is there any way to rectify this?

Comment: Unlikely, because even MS Excel has limits: depending on the version of MS Excel that you're using, the limit ranges from 1000 entries to 32768

Answer (score 0):

Hello_ mate.

I think the problem of your code is this row of code:

```
$objValidation->setFormula1("='autofill'!$A$1:$A$2");
```

try changing it to

```
$objValidation->setFormula1('=\'autofill\'!$A$1:$A$2');
```

It's because when you use double quotes `PHP` is treating `$A` as variables...

Good luck and let me know if this fixed your code

**EDIT**

Actually I did test your code now and seems to work. If you not change the code as I told you, there is just a **NOTICE** but the code still works. I see two sheets (autofill and Worksheet) and the second one has dropdown at **B2** with values 2,3(from autofill sheet). So try searching for the problem in other parts of your code or share it with us and we can see where is the problem.

**The code snippet that I tested(99% same as yours):**

```
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Creating auxiliary sheet for drop down data.
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet(0);
$objWorkSheet->setTitle("autofill");
$objWorkSheet->setCellValue('A1', 2)
        ->setCellValue('A2', 3);

$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2')->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
$objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
$objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
$objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
// Setting the formula in original sheet.
$objValidation->setFormula1('=\'autofill\'!$A$1:$A$2');

$objWriter = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('test.xlsx');
```

Comment: I am using 2.1 version of phpexcel.Only last lines of code differ as follows:                                                                                              $fileName = Slug($options["title"]) . ".xls";
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName );
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 

        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
        ob_end_clean();
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

Comment: @johndoe my version is `version    1.8.0, 2014-03-02` try saving the file as `xlsx` and using `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007`, this might solve your problem

Comment: @johndoe I did test using `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5` and I got reproduction of your problem. Seems the problem is coming from `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5` try with `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007`